# Tengo este error: Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, excepciones

Tengo este error en producción y no logro replicarlo, no sé que estoy haciendo mal, dejo el sp que puede estar molestando,parece que estoy usando mal el manejo de errores según lo que  he revisado por internet. si alguno ve en que me puedo estar equivocando se lo agradezco.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [opr].[sp_sel_valid_duplicado_operacion] 
 @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex           bigint
,@opr_cdg_operacion_filenet         nvarchar(100)
,@opr_cdg_rquest_cmx_past           bigint        = 0 output
,@opr_cdg_request_past              bigint        = 0 output
,@cdg_error                         integer       = null output
,@dsc_error                         nvarchar(100) = null output
AS
BEGIN
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @opr_cdg_idrequest bigint = null           
       SELECT @opr_cdg_request_past     = 0
       select @opr_cdg_rquest_cmx_past  = 0
       
 BEGIN TRY              
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM opr.stp_request_comex 
                       WHERE  opr_cdg_operacion_filenet = @opr_cdg_operacion_filenet
                         AND opr_cdg_idrequest_comex <> @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex )
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM opr.stp_request_comex 
                       WHERE  opr_cdg_operacion_filenet = @opr_cdg_operacion_filenet
                         AND opr_cdg_idrequest_comex <> @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                         AND upper(opr_nmb_canal_ingreso) = 'FILENET'
                         AND (opr_nmb_canal_instruccion IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(opr_nmb_canal_instruccion)) = '')
                         AND trans_cdg_idestado in (17,91,92,94,95,96,97,14))
        BEGIN
        
                    SELECT @opr_cdg_rquest_cmx_past = opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                          ,@opr_cdg_request_past = opr_cdg_idrequest
                        FROM opr.stp_request_comex 
                       WHERE  opr_cdg_operacion_filenet = @opr_cdg_operacion_filenet
                         AND opr_cdg_idrequest_comex <> @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                         AND upper(opr_nmb_canal_ingreso) = 'FILENET'
                         AND (opr_nmb_canal_instruccion IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(opr_nmb_canal_instruccion)) = '')
                         AND trans_cdg_idestado in (17,91,92,94,95,96,97,14)

                      SELECT  @opr_cdg_idrequest =  opr_cdg_idrequest
                      FROM opr.stp_request_comex 
                      WHERE opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                      
                      BEGIN TRAN 
                                delete from opr.stp_trx_id  where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_numero_sce where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                --datos comex M2
                                delete from opr.stp_correo_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_codigo_comercio_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_comision_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_cta_moneda_extranjera_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_cta_moneda_nacional_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_milestone_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_notas_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                --datos request M1
                                delete from opr.stp_correo_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_codigo_comercio_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_comision_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_cta_moneda_extranjera_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_cta_moneda_nacional_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_milestone_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_notas_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                --Datos M1 Y M2
                                delete from opr.stp_request_comex  where  opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_full_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                        
                                --UPDATE STP_LOG

                                UPDATE opr.stp_log
                                set opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_rquest_cmx_past 
                                ,opr_cdg_idrequest          = @opr_cdg_request_past 
                                where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                or opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest

                                SET @cdg_error = 4
                                SET @dsc_error = 'Validacion:ya existe el ID de Filenet en estado IF Liquidación'
                    COMMIT TRAN 
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
                    SET @cdg_error = 1
                    SET @dsc_error = 'Validacion:ya existe el ID de Filenet en la tabla opr.stp_request_comex'
        END         
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
                    SET @cdg_error = 2
                    SET @dsc_error = 'Validacion: ID de Filenet no encontrada en tabla opr.stp_request_comex.'
    END 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF XACT_STATE() = -1
                BEGIN
                        ROLLBACK TRAN 
                        
                        
   
                END 
                
                SET @cdg_error  = 3
                SET @dsc_error  = 'ha ocurrido un error en el proceso!'
END CATCH
END
```

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro, pero te sugiero que pruebes modificando `IF XACT_STATE() <> 0`

Comment: gracias @PatricioMoracho si es complicado, primero porque no sé como replicar y segundo porque ya esta en producción

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que confirmas la transacción en determinadas partes del procedimiento, pero en otras no.

Solo la confirmas si te sales por la linea 76. Pero si el procedimiento ha entrado por alguno de los else, hay una transación abierta que no se cierra.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [opr].[sp_sel_valid_duplicado_operacion] 
 @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex           bigint
,@opr_cdg_operacion_filenet         nvarchar(100)
,@opr_cdg_rquest_cmx_past           bigint        = 0 output
,@opr_cdg_request_past              bigint        = 0 output
,@cdg_error                         integer       = null output
,@dsc_error                         nvarchar(100) = null output
AS
BEGIN
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN -- Iniciar la transacción

DECLARE @opr_cdg_idrequest bigint = null           
       SELECT @opr_cdg_request_past     = 0
       select @opr_cdg_rquest_cmx_past  = 0
       
 BEGIN TRY              
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM opr.stp_request_comex 
                       WHERE  opr_cdg_operacion_filenet = @opr_cdg_operacion_filenet
                         AND opr_cdg_idrequest_comex <> @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex )
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM opr.stp_request_comex 
                       WHERE  opr_cdg_operacion_filenet = @opr_cdg_operacion_filenet
                         AND opr_cdg_idrequest_comex <> @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                         AND upper(opr_nmb_canal_ingreso) = 'FILENET'
                         AND (opr_nmb_canal_instruccion IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(opr_nmb_canal_instruccion)) = '')
                         AND trans_cdg_idestado in (17,91,92,94,95,96,97,14))
        BEGIN
        
                    SELECT @opr_cdg_rquest_cmx_past = opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                          ,@opr_cdg_request_past = opr_cdg_idrequest
                        FROM opr.stp_request_comex 
                       WHERE  opr_cdg_operacion_filenet = @opr_cdg_operacion_filenet
                         AND opr_cdg_idrequest_comex <> @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                         AND upper(opr_nmb_canal_ingreso) = 'FILENET'
                         AND (opr_nmb_canal_instruccion IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(opr_nmb_canal_instruccion)) = '')
                         AND trans_cdg_idestado in (17,91,92,94,95,96,97,14)

                      SELECT  @opr_cdg_idrequest =  opr_cdg_idrequest
                      FROM opr.stp_request_comex 
                      WHERE opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                      
                      BEGIN TRAN 
                                delete from opr.stp_trx_id  where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_numero_sce where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                --datos comex M2
                                delete from opr.stp_correo_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_codigo_comercio_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_comision_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_cta_moneda_extranjera_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_cta_moneda_nacional_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_milestone_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_notas_comex where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                --datos request M1
                                delete from opr.stp_correo_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_codigo_comercio_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_comision_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_cta_moneda_extranjera_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_cta_moneda_nacional_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_milestone_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                delete from opr.stp_notas_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                                --Datos M1 Y M2
                                delete from opr.stp_request_comex  where  opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                delete from opr.stp_full_request where opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest
                        
                                --UPDATE STP_LOG

                                UPDATE opr.stp_log
                                set opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_rquest_cmx_past 
                                ,opr_cdg_idrequest          = @opr_cdg_request_past 
                                where opr_cdg_idrequest_comex = @opr_cdg_idrequest_comex
                                or opr_cdg_idrequest = @opr_cdg_idrequest

                                SET @cdg_error = 4
                                SET @dsc_error = 'Validacion:ya existe el ID de Filenet en estado IF Liquidación'
                    --COMMIT TRAN 
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
                    SET @cdg_error = 1
                    SET @dsc_error = 'Validacion:ya existe el ID de Filenet en la tabla opr.stp_request_comex'
        END         
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
                    SET @cdg_error = 2
                    SET @dsc_error = 'Validacion: ID de Filenet no encontrada en tabla opr.stp_request_comex.'
    END 

    -- Confirmar la transación sea cual sea el resultado de la evaluación de las expresiónes.
    COMMIT TRAN 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@Trancount >0
                BEGIN
                        ROLLBACK TRAN 
                END 
                
                SET @cdg_error  = 3
                SET @dsc_error  = 'ha ocurrido un error en el proceso!'
END CATCH
END
```

He cambiando `Xact_state` por `@@TranCount`, porque aunque el funcionamiento es el mismo, me parece mucho más intuitivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Javi, voy a probar con esto. te comento

Comment: Javi para este caso me cambio el error, pero sigo sin poder replicar lo que pasa en producción

Comment: Te cambio el error, significa que tienes otro error. Que el que dices ya no lo tienes. Y tendrás que exponer cual es.....

Comment: Date cuenta que además de todas las sentencias que tiene el procedure, y por si fuera poco, tienes activado `set xact_Abort on`, que implica que si algo da error se aborte la transacción completa. Por tanto entre los dos millones de sentencias que tiene el procedure, si hay algo mal, nosotros no lo podemos ver.  Y por ejemplo la última update da un error de conversión porque el tipo de la tabla es int, y las variables que seteas son bigint, y no funcionaría tampoco. Por eso es superimportante identificar explicitamente el error.

Comment: Te entiendo Javi voy a validar eso igual, lo que pasa es que como les mencionaba es dificil igual porque yo no logro replicar ese error en desarrollo.

Comment: el error que vi yo cuando probé ese cambio en desarrollo es otro como si el cambio no me funcionara.